# PowerShell Script to Tune "Allows contributors to add or edit scriptable Web Parts." to webapplication

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I need to tune below option "**Allows contributors to add or edit scriptable Web Parts**" for particular web-application .

Can any one help me in getting this through powershell script
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bit of context, the page you are in can be found in

```
Central Administration > Security > Manage web part security
```

There are 3 properties there, all can be accessed through server object model.

```
$wa = get-spwebapplication http://contoso
$wa.AllowPartToPartCommunication
$wa.AllowAccessToWebPartCatalog
$wa.AllowContributorsToEditScriptableParts
```

You can tweak as a regular bool

```
$wa.AllowContributorsToEditScriptableParts = $true
$wa.Update()
```

If you are looking for solutions in the context of Office 365, I can't help you, but perhaps this can point you in the right direction.